# Image slider got stuck after first button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a question regarding an image slider that I am creating from scratch. I want to create it from scratch due to the fact that I do not need a lot of extra properties which I could get from using external sliders.

I have the following setup:

```js
var num_of_images = $( ".image-holder" ).length;
var visible_images = 2;

$( "#slide-right" ).click(function() {
  $(".hold-1").addClass('first');
});
```

```css
.col-slider{
 position:relative;
 z-index:13;
 margin-top:0px;   
 width:70%;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:174px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.image-holder {
 width: 175px;
 height: 174px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color: white;
 margin:0 15px;  
 float:left;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))
}
.image-holder h2{
 font-family: Titillium Web;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight:600;
 display:inline-block;
 width:85%;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:36px;
}
.col-slider-buttons a{
  margin-right:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.first {
 -webkit-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
     -ms-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
      -o-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
         animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes animateleft {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-o-keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-slider-buttons">
  <a id="slide-left" href="#">Left</a>
  <a id="slide-right" href="#">Right</a>
</div>
<div class="col-slider">
  <div class="image-holder hold-1">
    <h2>TEST 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image-holder hold-2">
    <h2>TEST 2</h2>
  </div>          
  <div class="image-holder hold-3">
    <h2>TEST 3</h2>
  </div> 
  <div class="image-holder hold-4">
    <h2>TEST 4</h2>
  </div>    
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that whenever I press the right button the margin got shifted towards the left. But I need some kind of mechanism to detect that. Have anyone an idea on how I could implement that? I do not ask for full code implementations. Any guidance is already very helpfull.

To be short: desired setup: being able to navigate through the images with the left and right button by shifting the margin towards left and right.

For a JSFIDDLE DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pw7janey/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added/changed these lines of code:

```
$(".hold-"+ ($('.image-holder.first').length + 1)).addClass('first');
```

What it does: It counts the amount of elements that has both class' `image-holder` & `first`. Then i adds 1, to get the value of the `hold-` class we want to add our class to

```js
var num_of_images = $(".image-holder").length;
var visible_images = 2;
$("#slide-right").click(function() {
  $(".hold-"+ ($('.image-holder.first').length + 1)).addClass('first');
});
```

```css
.col-slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 13;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 174px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image-holder {
  width: 175px;
  height: 174px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 15px;
  float: left;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))
}

.image-holder h2 {
  font-family: Titillium Web;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.col-slider-buttons a {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.first {
  -webkit-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
  -ms-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
  -o-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
  animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes "animateleft" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -185px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animateleft {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -185px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "animateleft" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -185px;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "animateleft" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -185px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "animateleft" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -185px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-slider-buttons">
  <a id="slide-left" href="#">Left</a>
  <a id="slide-right" href="#">Right</a>
</div>
<div class="col-slider">
  <div class="image-holder hold-1">
    <h2>TEST 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image-holder hold-2">
    <h2>TEST 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image-holder hold-3">
    <h2>TEST 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image-holder hold-4">
    <h2>TEST 4</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep. Awesome that will help me, I already build a stopper. So that it will stop adding classes when the last image is reached. Any ideas on combining it with the left button? What should I do? Remove the class with animation?

Comment: @Rotan075 currently i dont have a solution for you to fix that. Maybe make a new question. Think someone in `css` can easily help you out

Answer (score 2):

You are only adding the class `first` to your first holder.. (.hold-1). You can add an additional variable (counter) and add it the following way:

```
$(".hold-" + counter +"").addClass('first');
```

Have a look below:

```js
var num_of_images = $( ".image-holder" ).length;
var visible_images = 2;
var counter = 1;

$( "#slide-right" ).click(function() {
  $(".hold-" + counter +"").addClass('first');
  counter = counter + 1;
});
```

```css
.col-slider{
 position:relative;
 z-index:13;
 margin-top:0px;   
 width:70%;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:174px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.image-holder {
 width: 175px;
 height: 174px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color: white;
 margin:0 15px;  
 float:left;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))
}
.image-holder h2{
 font-family: Titillium Web;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight:600;
 display:inline-block;
 width:85%;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:36px;
}
.col-slider-buttons a{
  margin-right:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.first {
 -webkit-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
    -moz-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
     -ms-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
      -o-animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
         animation: animateleft 1s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes animateleft {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}

@-o-keyframes "animateleft" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -185px;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-slider-buttons">
  <a id="slide-left" href="#">Left</a>
  <a id="slide-right" href="#">Right</a>
</div>
<div class="col-slider">
  <div class="image-holder hold-1">
    <h2>TEST 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image-holder hold-2">
    <h2>TEST 2</h2>
  </div>          
  <div class="image-holder hold-3">
    <h2>TEST 3</h2>
  </div> 
  <div class="image-holder hold-4">
    <h2>TEST 4</h2>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Hope it helped